References under the same shortauthor
I want to make something like this, where references with same shortauthor but different shorttitle are ordered in this way:
this is a MWE, I'm using philosophy-verbose as bibstyle:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
            \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
            \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english}
            \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
            \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}

  \usepackage[%
            bibstyle=philosophy-verbose,%
            citestyle=authoryear,%
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber,%
            classical = true,%
            scauthors = bibcite,%
            dashed = true,%trattino al posto del nome dell'autore nelle entrate multiple
            volnumformat = parens,%
            volumeformat = Roman,%
            firstinits=true,%
            volnumformat=strings,%
            volumeformat=romansc,%
            sorting=nyt,%
            relatedformat=brackets,%
            editionformat=superscript,
            indexing]{biblatex}
            
            \usepackage{polyglossia} 
            \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
            \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english}
            \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}
            \setkeys{latin}{variant=modern}
            
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{pipi,
keywords = {edizione},
title = {Le Pitiche},
author = {Pindaro},
editor = {Bruno Gentili and Paola Angela Bernardini and Ettore Cingano and Pietro Giannini},
address = {Milano},
year = {1995},
shorthand = {Pi.}
}

@book{piol,
keywords = {edizione},
title = {Le Olimpiche},
author = {Pindaro},
editor = {Bruno Gentili and Paola Angela Bernardini and Ettore Cingano and Pietro Giannini},
address = {Milano},
year = {1995},
shorthand = {Pi.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbiblist{shorthand}
\end{document}

